# HELP! Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: magento2

> Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

This error occurs in two places:

1. when I try to connect Marketplace.
2. when I try to integrate with Paypal gateway.

In the command line, i curl a SSL site.  It returns fine. **Any help will be appreciated**